# PHP Variable in session not getting updated instantly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

In two different php file one sets variable in session and other reads from it. while updated the second file gets the old value immediately after.

I have two consecutive jQuery ajax call from my page.

1. Tokens that fetch access token from remote server and set it in $_SESSION[token]. If it already finds a valid token in session does nothing.
2. /makeReq which calls another api with the token from $_SESSION[token]

I check if a session gets expired considering it's grant time and expiry. When it's expired it fetch and sets the new token in $_SESSION[token] but in the second call when reading from $_Session[token] it gets the old value.

These are two separate jQuery ajax call from a single page.

Below is the code for my token endpoint.

```php
$current_time = time();

$get_new_token = true;
$request_token = null;

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $request_token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $last_token_expire_time = $request_token['grant_time'] + $request_token['expires_in'] -600;
    $get_new_token = $last_token_expire_time < $current_time ? true : false;
}

if ($get_new_token) {
    $request_token=get_token();
    $request_token['grant_time'] = time();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $request_token;
}
```

Below is the code for my makeReq endpoint

```php
 $header=array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'authorization:'.$_SESSION["token"],
            'x-app-key:'.APP_KEY
        );
```

Below is the code from where I am making the request

```
jQuery.ajax({
       url: "'.plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "token.php".'",
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (data) {
       }
});
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "'.plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "makeReq.php".'",
        type:"POST",
        data: {formData: postData},
        success: function(data) {
                 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cache issue.
Try to eliminate anything that may interfere with cache. If you are on a wp dedicated hosting, such as WpEngine, please note that they encourage not to use sessions at all.

Also, make you code with only the essential parts, just to see if you lose the session.

Comment: As i am from java background, searching for some thing like global static variable to get the work done quickly. Can you suggest any alternative other than using session

Comment: I would recommend to save a hash into cookie, and this hash will refer to the token on a DB record. This way you are not risking by showing the token, and use simple cookie to restore the token from a reliable engine (DB).